# How to handle an html\php projects using Aptana?

Tags: php, eclipse, aptana

I am pretty new in php\html (I came from Java), in Java I use Eclipse and so I decided to use Aptana Studio for html\php (because its interface is very similar to Eclipse interface) but now I have a doubt about how handle my project

I use Ubuntu and I have installed **Apache2** web server and so my websites are put into **/var/www** directory.

What have I to set as Aptana workspace? Can I set my **/var/www* direcotory as Aptana workspace and then see all subdirectory as Aptana project?

Or am I missing something?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1):

you dont see the subdirectories because the "Project Explorer" only shows projects, so you have to create a project for that folder, eclipse does the same, and aptana is pretty much just a modified eclipse.

also /var/www seems like a good workspace for your web projects, that is also how i do it.

Side note: If you are developing on a running local webserver and the port is forwarded in your router, people could theoretically access your developing content and exploit security issues, so either block the port or secure the server in some other way

Comment: What I mean is: "I set /var/www as my workspace, then I create a new project named MyProject and it is created the directory /var/www/MyProject and I work here so I can test it on my web server, is it a smart solution or not?

Comment: yes, as i said, its how i do it, and i think its probably the best way to do it. because you can just save and refresh the browser after edits, no copying around and stuff